# Header in SSRS has overwrite the upper level

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The code is working fine and able to display data... but, some data cause the date header to be brought up to the above header.
and below the image.... i wonder is it the cause of the sql query, or ssrs when i formatting the tablix?

I cannot get all codes here, link to sql query

[image: SSRS grouping and error]

[SQL query here](http://textuploader.com/ddusi)

Comment: SQL Query is here http://textuploader.com/ddusi

Comment: ok... it is only happen on the first week... if there is no data on the first few days... instead of showing 1-Jan, it will bring up the second level's date till the date which has data,

Comment: It needs to start on Monday, that is why the date is screwed, and it back to normal once it reached the start date of the activity ....